# Collect values from a column, clear the column and copy those values to another column

Tags: google-apps-script

Column A after clear:

| A |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

I need to get the values from a column before clearing that column, but I can only copy the values after clearing:

```
function lista_de_episodios_rc() {
  var page = 'copy';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(page);
  
  var history = ss.getRange(page + '!A1:A');

  var to_del = 'A1:A'
  ss.getRange(to_del + ss.getMaxRows()).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  history.copyTo(ss.getRange(page + '!C1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

In this attempt, column C remains empty.

Is there a way to store these values for use after cleaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is quite a manual but working approach:

You can use `getValues()` and `setValues()` to get the values from the source column and set it in the target column.

```js
function move() {
  Logger.log("Starting script...")

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Range for 4 values in the first column
  const sourceColumn = ss.getRange(1, 1, 4, 1);
  // Range for 4 values in the second column 
  const targetColumn = ss.getRange(1, 2, 4, 1);

  // get values from source 
  const col1Content = sourceColumn.getValues();
  // clear the source column
  sourceColumn.clear();
  // now set the target values
  targetColumn.setValues(col1Content);

  Logger.log("Done.")
}
```

#### Input

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b |  |
| c |  |
| d |  |

#### Output

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  | a |
|  | b |
|  | c |
|  | d |

For other approaches I suggest you look at the [documentation for Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) which describes a lot of other methods you could use to move the content. There are also different versions of `copy()` and `clear()` which allow you to specify whether you want to keep formats, data validation etc. or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to get all values in a column, and move them to another column:

```
function lista_de_episodios_rc() {

  const fromCol = `A`
  const toCol = `C`

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`copy`)
  const range = sheet.getRange(`${fromCol}:${fromCol}`)
  const values = range.getValues().filter(cell => cell !== ``)
  
  range.clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(`${toCol}1:${toCol}${values.length+1}`).setValues(values)

}
```